# MySQL - How to convert number to decimal using stored precision/scale?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of payments where each record has a `currency_id`.  When I `SELECT` a payment, I want to format the value as a decimal with the correct number of decimal places.  The currency table has a column called `decimals`.

```
SELECT p.sale
 , CONVERT(p.amount, DECIMAL(21,c.decimals)) as formatted_amount
FROM payment p 
JOIN currency c ON p.currency_id=c.id
```

When I do this I get `Syntax error or access violation: 1064`.

Comment: See if putting  `decimals` inside back-ticks changes anything.

Comment: It doesn't change anything - same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the only way to accomplish the stated goal was with a statement like this:

```
SELECT p.sale
, (CASE WHEN c.decimals=0 THEN CONVERT(p.amount,DECIMAL(21,0))
    WHEN c.decimals=1 THEN CONVERT(p.amount,DECIMAL(21,1))
    WHEN c.decimals=2 THEN CONVERT(p.amount,DECIMAL(21,2))
    ELSE p.amount END) as formatted_amount
FROM payment p 
JOIN currency c ON p.currency_id=c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

M and D in DECIMAL(M,D) can only be const number, like DECIMAL(5,2).

Comment: Thanks - so how do I accomplish my goal as stated in the title?

Comment: The easiest way may be find the max length for decimals are specify it as a const in SQL.

Comment: I can't do that because each record has a different currency and each record will have a different format.